# Mongoid push new embedded document in a single query

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

We use mongoid to store a users score:

```
class UserScore
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :user_id, type: Integer
  field :points,  type: Integer, default: 0
  embeds_many :activities
end
```

We keep track of the activities of a user by collecting them in embedded documents called activities. As the number of activities grows, the time to access user.user_score also does if mongoid will load all embedded documents. If we add a new activity, it always results in two querys:

```
UserScore.where( user_id: user.id ).first.activities << Activity.new(values)
```

One query to find the UserScores and one query to push.

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=development collection=user_scores selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>121920}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil 
(192.1866ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=development collection=user_scores selector={"_id"=>"53cfe22869d256929d000139"} update={"$push"=>{"activities"=>{"_id"=>"54ed824d4c5c34f157000011", "points"=>50, "created_at"=>2015-02-25 08:05:33 UTC}}} flags=[] 
(0.5269ms)
```

The find-query isn't realy necessary as we could also push an new embedded document by using moped like this:

```
Mongoid::Sessions.default[:user_scores].find(user_id: user.id).update('$push' => {'activities' => values)})

MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=development collection=user_scores selector={:user_id=>125721} update={"$push"=>{"activities"=>{:points=>50, "_id"=>"54ed80224c5c34f157000007", :created_at=>2015-02-25 07:56:18 UTC}}} flags=[] 
(0.5438ms)
```

Is there a way to achieve this in mongoid? 
The reason we want to use mongoid is that we want to process the new activity as a ruby object. Also by pushing the values like this, the activity documents are missing the _id and created_at field that we have to create in the application which leads to more ugly code.

We use mongoid 3.1.6. Is it possible that a kind of lazy loading was or will be added in later versions ?

**Update:**

We mock the relation between user and user score because user is stored in a mysql database:

```
class User
  def user_score
    UserScore.where(user_id: self.id).first
  end
end
```

So we can not use the relation like this

```
user.user_score << Activity.new(values)
```

without the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research it seems like there is no alternative to the method I described in my question. Mongoid always loads the whole document with embedded documents. If you use only(), you can not manipulate the document.

I also noticed that the push into the array becomes inefficient if you have more then a few thousand embedded document. The solution for the two problems was to move the embedded documents to a seperate collection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
a = Activity.new(values)
a.user_score = user.user_score
a.save
```

This may require you to write the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relations that you're already storing the data for:

```
class UserScore
    belongs_to :user
end

class User
    has_many :user_scores
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately we mock the relation between user and user_score because user is stored in mysql. I updated the question.

Comment: Try the equivalent, instead of `user.user_score`, do `a.user_score = <your_mysql_find_query>`